# Count n last records in each group in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a fairly complex query to count rows  and with the expansion of the number of data in the database I realize that it becomes terribly slow (5,800 ms !!!)

I have a table  PHOTOS and a table ALBUMS. I must count the number of pictures by taking the 7 latest pictures (max) added (I am using the auto-increment ID field for that) of each album.

```
SELECT count(P.ID) 
FROM PHOTOS P, ALBUMS A 
WHERE (
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM PHOTOS AS f 
    WHERE   f.ID_ALBUM = P.ID_ALBUM 
    AND f.ID > P.ID) < 8 
AND A.ID=P.ID_ALBUM
```

It works but it very slow ; (

If anyone sees another way to highlight these, I thank him !!!

Comment: "I must count the number of pictures by taking the 7 latest pictures (max) added".  Please clarify your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I have some albums in the table ALBUMS with a row ID autoincrement. In another table PHOTOS i have some pictures with a row ID autoincrement too and a row ID_ALBUM to attach picture to an album. For an album i can have 3 pictures or 5O pictures ... I need just return for each album the 8 latest pictures (or less if the album count 1 or 2 pictures for example) and sum of all.